# realpath -L vs -P

Tags: symlink, coreutils

From coreutils manual

> `-L` `--logical` Symbolic links are resolved in the specified file
>   names, but they are resolved after any subsequent `..` components are
>   processed.
>
> `-P` `--physical` Symbolic links are resolved in the specified file
>   names, and they are resolved before any subsequent `..` components are
>   processed. This is the default mode of operation.

Am I correct that the difference between the two options is in the order of processing symbolic links and processing `..`?

Could you explain  how the two options make difference, and maybe provide some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct in that the order is changed, looking at the code the difference in `-L` compared to `-P` is that it is that the function doing the canonization (`canonicalize_filename_mode`) is called twice, first with the `CAN_NOLINKS` flag then without (latter call is like the one for `-P`), whereas the flag is described as `Don't expand symlinks.`. I still have no idea what the real-world differences are.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the difference is in the order of processing `..` and symbolic links.

Here's an example of how this can make a difference.  I have an external disk mounted at `/root/Archives`, and a symbolic link pointing to it from my home:

```
$ pwd
/home/katsura

$ ls -ld Archives
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct 23  2013 Archives -> /root/Archives
```

`realpath` resolves the symlink:

```
$ realpath Archives
/root/Archives

$ realpath -L Archives
/root/Archives
```

However:

```
$ realpath Archives/../foo
/root/foo

$ realpath -L Archives/../foo
/home/katsura/foo
```

With no option (or with `-P`) the symlink is resolved first, so `Archives` becomes `/root/Archives`, then `..` is applied.

With `-L` the `..` is applied first, so `Archives/..` becomes `/home/katsura`, then the *remaining* symlinks are resolved.  Since there are no symlinks left, the result is just `/home/katsura`.

Comment: thanks. is the case where a symlink is followed by `..` the only case where `-P` and `-L` make difference?

Comment: @Tim Of course not.  Think out of the box, there might be other symlinks along the way.  Also, I've been cheating above: if `/root/foo` is actually a symlink to `/home/katsura/foo`, then the result of `realpath Archives/../foo` is the same as `realpath -L Archives/../foo`.  As I said, think out of the box.

Comment: So `realpath -L` will return the path as it is understood by shells? Like switching to a symbollically linked directory and then typing `cd ..` will bring you up out of the symbolic link.

Comment: @Melab "Shells" don't do that.  It's just `bash` and (I think) `zsh` that try to pretend they're doing it, by keeping track of your `cd`s.  I don't think either `bash` or `zsh` have anything to do with `realpath`, but yes, I suppose you can look at it that way.